# Python - User-defined classes have __cmp__() and __hash__() methods by default? Or?

Tags: python, methods, comparison, default

In the python [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) ([yeah, I have this thing with the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674428/python-supports-a-limited-form-of-multiple-inheritance-in-what-way-limited)) it says that:

> User-defined classes have `__cmp__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns `id(x)`.

But the following code shows another thing:

```
>>> class Test(object): pass
...
>>> t = Test()
>>>
>>> t.__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of Test object at 0x01F2B5D0>
>>>
>>> t.__cmp__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '__cmp__'
>>>
```

So where is `__cmp__` or what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is a bit misleading. To get the full story, you have to read up on [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__), namely this part:

> If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity (“address”).

So, basically, you don't get a `__cmp__` method by default, but instances of user-defined classes can be compared to other objects; if the instance has no `__cmp__` method, the object identity (determined by `id(obj)`, which is usually the memory address of the object) will be used instead.